# Objective C: Facebook access alert view not dismissed when we select ok to granted

Tags: objective-c, iphone, slcomposeviewcontroller

when i navigate to profiles page in my app it displayed popup message for Granting access to Facebook from my app.

its works fine for don't allow

When i tap on ok it gets granted access but the alert view displayed again and again. How to avoid this issue or remove alert once granted / not alllowed

[image]

```
//setupSocialConfigeration
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init] ;
    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType =  [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"258220404379843", ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dictFB completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSLog(@"xxxx");
         }
     }];
```

Comment: I'm not sure but try saveAccount:withCompletionHandler: for the accountStore if granted.

Comment: And try to check bundle id on Facebook app.

Comment: Yes the issues is in bundle id on Facebook app not match with my app bundle id. Thanks alot s